# ¿Cómo hacer para insertar enlaces en determinadas palabras de un texto con javascript?

Tags: javascript, enlace

Se trataría de insertar diferentes links en determinadas palabras de un texto con javascript del mismo modo en que funciona por ejemplo Infolinks (pero sin crear ningún tooltip al pasar el cursor del ratón por encima del hipervínculo, simplemente enlaces).

Por favor, preferiría que lo explicaran en **JavaScript plano**, sin JQuery. Gracias

Lo  estoy intentando hacer con este sencillo código de Javascript en HTML, pero algo falla. ¿Podrían decirme cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo?

```js
function linkar(texto, link){
        html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        re = new RegExp(texto, 'g');
        if(re.test(html)){
            html  = html.replace(re, '<a href="' + link + '" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">' + texto + '</a>');
        }
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
        }
    
     
      vinculos = ['casa':'https://es.wikipedia.com', 'Tenerife':'https://www.google.com'];

      for(var clave in vinculos){
      linkar(clave, vinculos[clave]);
      }
```

```html
<p>La casa tiene 200 m2 y está situada en Tenerife. Tiene cuatro ventanas y dos puertas.</p>
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Para que podamos ayudarte no solo has de explicar lo que deseas conseguir si no mostrar lo intentado. Añade tambien [mcve] que muestre exactamente lo que pretendes hacer. Mira el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y a hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo por tu cuenta? La filosofía de SO es ayudar con problemas específicos de código o programación. No hacemos las tareas o deberes,  pero si que te ayudamos si tienes un problema específico y demuestras que lo has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Nota: jQuery **es** javascript

Comment: Lo  estoy intentando hacer con este sencillo código de Javascript en HTML, pero algo falla. ¿Podrían decirme cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo?

Comment: Un array no puede contener los : dentro, por lo que o cambias el array a vinculos = ['https://es.wikipedia.com', 'https://www.google.com']; o sino crea un objeto vinculo. vinculos = {'casa':'https://es.wikipedia.com', 'Tenerife':'https://www.google.com'};

Comment: Muchas gracias, Iñigo, por tu ayuda. Ahora sí funciona. Era ese fallo de sintaxis. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes llenar el arreglo usando los índices textuales, al hacer la asignación los índices textuales también se crean.

```
vinculos['indice textual'] = valor;
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <p>La casa tiene 200 m2 y está situada en Tenerife. Tiene cuatro ventanas y dos puertas.</p>

  <script>
    function linkar(texto, link) {
      html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
      re = new RegExp(texto, 'g');
      if (re.test(html)) {
        html = html.replace(re, '<a href="' + link + '" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">' + texto + '</a>');
      }
      document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
    }

    vinculos = [];
    vinculos['casa'] = 'https://es.wikipedia.com';
    vinculos['Tenerife'] = 'https://www.google.com';

    for (var clave in vinculos) {
      linkar(clave, vinculos[clave]);
    }
  </script>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Ruslan.